# Extension to generic struct where element is generic struct

Tags: swift, generics

I have a generic structs `FutureValue<Element>` and `Failable<Element>`, which both implement `map`…

```
struct FutureValue<Element> {
   func map<U>(_ t: (Element) -> U) -> FutureValue<U> …
}

struct Failable<Element> {
   func map<U>(_ t: (Element) -> U) -> Failable<U> …
}
```

I'd like to write an extension on `FutureValue` to specialise it when its `Element` is *any* `Failable`, so that I can implement a `map` like function that maps on the contained `Element` in the `FutureValue<Failable<Element>>`

How can I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to create a protocol that captures "any Failable" and captures the pieces you want for your algorithm.

```
protocol AnyFailable {
    associatedtype Element
    func map<U>(_ t: (Element) -> U) -> Failable<U>
}
```

And express that all Failables are AnyFailable.

```
extension Failable: AnyFailable {}
```

You may want to add methods on the protocol to extract data you need or provide methods.

Then, create your extension:

```
extension FutureValue where Element: AnyFailable {
    func map<U>(_ t: (Element.Element) -> U) -> FutureValue<Failable<U>> {
        // You will probably need to provide your own implementation here
        return FutureValue<Failable<U>>(element: element.map(t))
    }
}
```

---

It's worth noting how I constructed this. I started by writing a more concrete form based on `String` (just to pick a random thing):

```
extension FutureValue where Element == Failable<String> {
    func map<U>(_ t: (String) -> U) -> FutureValue<Failable<U>> {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I wrote a simple piece of consuming code:

```
let f = FutureValue(element: Failable(element: "alice"))
print(f.map { $0.first })
```

And from there, I extracted the pieces I needed into a protocol. This tends to get you moving in the right direction, step by step. It is very challenging sometimes to jump directly to the most generic form.

Comment: Ah – specifically, both `FutureValue` and `Failable` implement `map`, which is itself generic, and I can't quite see how to put this in to the protocol. I'll add this in…

Comment: It's the same; you just need to add the parts that you need to consume. An Element associated type, and a map. Edited.

Comment: Hi Rob – thank you again for the answer, it was very helpful. I've gone with a slightly different approach and described it in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56124498/2547229). I think it's simpler in a case like this of just wanting the protocol as a constraint? I thought you might find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Rob for his [super answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56093976/2547229).

The approach I took in the end is slightly different so I'm adding it as a second answer. For the case of an extension to a generic that is constrained on the element being of some kind, I feel this approach is simpler. It's also a readily introduced "pattern" that can be easily dropped in to similar situations.

```
/* 
 Protocol for things that can be _concretely_ represented as a `Failable`.
 I keep it private so it's just used to constrain the protocol extension
 below.
*/
private protocol AsFailable {
    associatedtype Element
    var asFailable: Failable<Element> {get}
}

/*
 `Failable` can definitely be represented `AsFailable`…
*/
extension Failable: AsFailable {
    var asFailable: Failable<Element> {
        return self
    }
}

/*
 Use the `AsFailable` protocol to constrain an extension to `FutureValue`
 for any `FutureValue` who's `Element` is a `Failable`.
*/
extension FutureValue where Element: AsFailable {    
    func happyMap<U>(_ t: @escaping (Element.Element) -> U) 
    -> FutureValue<Failable<U>>  {
        return map { $0.asFailable.map(t) }
    }
}
```

Rob's approach let me implement `map` (as set out in the OP), but I started to flounder when I wanted to implement `flatMap` as well. Switching to the use of `AsFailable` let me quickly write a simple implementation of `flatMap`.

I think the `AsXXX` approach is simper for a case like this where a protocol is *just* required to act as a constraint.

Here's what `happyFlatMap` looks like:

```
func happyFlatMap<U>(_ t: @escaping (FailableElement) -> FutureValue<Failable<U>>)
    -> FutureValue<Failable<U>>
{
    typealias Out = FutureValue<Failable<U>>
    return flatMap {
        failable in
        switch failable.asFailable {

        case let .happy(element):
            return t(element)

        case let .error(error):
            return Out(Failable<U>.error(error))

        case let .canceled(reason):
            return Out(Failable<U>.canceled(reason))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I love the generalness of this solution, but I'm troubled by the `.as...` spelling. That's generally discouraged in Swift. We say `Int.init?(string:)`, not `String.asInt` (and that's intentional; I don't think there are any `.as...` methods in stdlib). I'm trying to figure out if that can be fixed, either just by changing the name (though we also tend to avoid names like "reify" or whatever), or with an init, but I'm not finding it immediately. Do you have gist or git repo that has this entire code? I'd like to play with it more.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the feedback! … Interesting. Can you link to why this approach is disliked? I assume renaming to `FailureRepresentable` doesn't really address the concern :-) I was hoping this protocol could be `private`, but then the constrained `extension` is also `private`, which defeats the purpose. I don't have the code in a public repo yet, but I'm planning to, so I'll try to do it sooner rather than later.

Comment: @RobNapier A bit rough, and I need to find out how to properly package a library, but [here it is](https://github.com/benjohnbarnes/TinyFuture). Thanks!

Comment: @RobNapier I'm just monkeying about with this hoping to improve it 4 years later  due to a new suggested reply. I didn't find an way that isn't fundamentally an `asBlah` approach though. Did you come up with anything, or a nicer way to spell it? All the best!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to specify such conditions for a function in an extension without additional protocols:

```
extension FutureValue {
    func map<In, Out>(_ t: (In) -> Out) -> FutureValue<Failable<Out>> where FutureElement == Failable<In> { .init() }
}
```

Comment: Hi Olex, this does not work I think. The function your suggested `map` takes is _from_ any generic thing to a `Future<Failable<U>>`. But the function it **should** take (from the question) is from an `(FutureElement.FailableElement) -> U`. Swift doesn't let us express constraint on the required function's argument using a `where` condition.

Comment: Hey, Benjohn. I think now I understand what it should do. See the updated code. BTW `where` clause works just fine.